# Using BindingOperations with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to use the static methods of the BindingOperations class to make an async wrapper for the ObservableCollection but it's difficult to find any good examples of how to use it.

Simply calling BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _lock) in the constructor of the wrapper appears to work very well as I'm able to add items to the collection from threads other than the UI-thread without problem.

However, I'm also trying to use BindingOperations.AccessCollection(this, ()=>{...}, true) to sort the collection and limit the amount of items but I'm getting exceptions as if it has been modified elsewhere while it was supposed to be locked.

For example:

> **RemoveAt(Count - 1);** randomly gives a **ArgumentOutOfRangeException**

And:

> **MoveItem(oldIndex, newIndex);** sometimes gives a **InvalidOperationException: collection was modified**

So clearly it's not locking despite msdn saying:

> "Provides access to a collection by using the synchronization
>   mechanism that the application specified when it called
>   EnableCollectionSynchronization."

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.accesscollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Any idea what I have missed?

```
public class AsyncObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private object _collectionLock = new object();
    private int _maxLength = 0;
    private bool _reversed = false;
    private Func<T, object> _sortOrder = null;

    public AsyncObservableCollection()
        : this(0, null)
    {
    }
    public AsyncObservableCollection(int maxLength)
        : this(maxLength, null)
    {
    }
    public AsyncObservableCollection(int maxLength, bool reversed)
        : this(maxLength, reversed, null)
    {
    }
    public AsyncObservableCollection(int maxLength, Func<T, object> sortOrder)
        : this(maxLength, false, sortOrder)
    {
    }
    public AsyncObservableCollection(int maxLength, bool reversed, Func<T, object> sortOrder)
    {
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _collectionLock);

        if (maxLength > 0)
            _maxLength = maxLength;
        _reversed = reversed;
        _sortOrder = sortOrder;
    }

    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        BindingOperations.AccessCollection(this, () => {
            if (!_reversed)
                base.Add(item);
            else
                Insert(0, item);
        }, true);

        Sort();
        Limit();
    }

    public void Limit()
    {
        Limit(_maxLength);
    }
    public void Limit(int maxLength)
    {
        if (maxLength > 0)
        {
            BindingOperations.AccessCollection(this, () => {
                while (Count > 0 && Count > maxLength)
                    if (!_reversed)
                        RemoveAt(0);
                    else
                        RemoveAt(Count - 1);
            }, true);
        }
    }

    public void Sort()
    {
        Sort(_sortOrder);
    }
    public void Sort(Func<T, object> order)
    {
        if (order != null)
        {
            BindingOperations.AccessCollection(this, () => {
                List<T> list = this.ToList();
                List<T> sortedList = !_reversed ? list.OrderBy(order).ToList() : list.OrderByDescending(order).ToList();

                foreach (T item in list)
                {
                    int oldIndex = list.IndexOf(item);
                    int newIndex = sortedList.IndexOf(item);
                    if (oldIndex != newIndex)
                        MoveItem(oldIndex, newIndex);
                }
            }, true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution (not an answer to the actual question regarding the BindingOperations class):**

Problem solved by simply locking using the same lock-object supplied to BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization():

```
public class AsyncObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    private object _collectionLock = new object();
    private int _maxLength = 0;
    private bool _reversed = false;
    private Func<T, object> _sortOrder = null;

    public AsyncObservableCollection()
        : this(0, null)
    {
    }
    public AsyncObservableCollection(int maxLength)
        : this(maxLength, null)
    {
    }
    public AsyncObservableCollection(int maxLength, bool reversed)
        : this(maxLength, reversed, null)
    {
    }
    public AsyncObservableCollection(int maxLength, Func<T, object> sortOrder)
        : this(maxLength, false, sortOrder)
    {
    }
    public AsyncObservableCollection(int maxLength, bool reversed, Func<T, object> sortOrder)
    {
        BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization(this, _collectionLock);

        if (maxLength > 0)
            _maxLength = maxLength;
        _reversed = reversed;
        _sortOrder = sortOrder;
    }

    public void AddSortLimit(T item)
    {
        lock (_collectionLock)
            if (!_reversed)
                Add(item);
            else
                Insert(0, item);

        Sort();
        Limit();
    }

    public void Limit()
    {
        Limit(_maxLength);
    }
    public void Limit(int maxLength)
    {
        if (maxLength > 0)
        {
            lock (_collectionLock)
                while (Count > 0 && Count > maxLength)
                    if (!_reversed)
                        RemoveAt(0);
                    else
                        RemoveAt(Count - 1);
        }
    }

    public void Sort()
    {
        Sort(_sortOrder);
    }
    public void Sort(Func<T, object> order)
    {
        if (order != null)
        {
            lock (_collectionLock)
            {
                List<T> list = this.ToList();
                List<T> sortedList = !_reversed ? list.OrderBy(order).ToList() : list.OrderByDescending(order).ToList();

                foreach (T item in list)
                {
                    int oldIndex = IndexOf(item);
                    int newIndex = sortedList.IndexOf(item);
                    if (oldIndex != newIndex)
                        MoveItem(oldIndex, newIndex);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you use this collection? Do you only use these methods, or do you call other methods from the base class (ObservableCollection) as well?

Comment: I'm a bit concerned about your `public new void Add(T item)`. You should override the `protected virtual` methods of the `ObservableCollection` instead of trying to replace the public ones.

Comment: @PouyaAbadi Currently I'm only using these methods.

Comment: @grek40 I found SetItem(int index, T item) to override but it doesn't seem right since it takes an *int index* and I want to decide whether to add the item first or last depending on if the list is in reverse order or not.

Comment: Well, you can provide an additional method for that, but you shouldn't implement the locking on this level and you can't expect __all__ callers to use your version of `Add`. The locking should be in the protected functions like `SetItem`, otherwise you will miss some calls and then you wonder why you get exceptions.

Comment: @grek40 In this case I don't excpect anyone else to use this implementation of Add. It could be called AddAndSortAndLimit to make it less confusing for the consumer. Also, I don't know if I can lock at a deeper level since MoveItem() may be using SetItem() and I need the lock for the duration of the sorting in Sort().

Comment: @GetOffMyWifi you are free to double-lock nested on the same thread (at least by directly taking the lock object, I don't know how `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` reacts)

Comment: @grek40 Great to learn something new. I simply assumed that locking twice would cause a deadlock. While this doesn't answer the actual question regarding the BindingOperations class, it does allow me to skip using the BindingOperations.AccessCollection() method entirely as locking using the same lock-object supplied to BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization() works without any problems after extensive testing. Edited question to include the solution.

Comment: @GetOffMyWifi good to hear that it works for you. Would be interesting if someone can explain why specifically your former approach caused problems, but I'm not quite sure if that can be answered without background information on the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) MoveItem(oldIndex, newIndex); sometimes gives a InvalidOperationException: >collection was modified.

You are getting error because you are modifying the same list on which you are iterating. So iterate on sorted list and move item is the list collection.

> 2) RemoveAt(Count - 1); randomly gives a ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Put a condition to check (Count-1) is less then the list.Count.

Comment: 1) I don't think that is correct. The variables *list* and *sortedList* should be local copies of *this* as I understand it and I'm modifying *this*... 2) There is no list variable here. The class that you're looking at is the list. Checking if Count-1 is less than Count is obviously pointless.

Comment: @GetOffMyWifi While you are right on the copies part, you still screw your results, because after the first `MoveItem`, the following `list.IndexOf(item)` calls will be inconsistent with `this.IndexOf(item)` and so you will not move the intended items around.

Comment: My first point is saying same as grek40 explain. have you solved you problem?

Comment: @Rudra That might have been what you meant but it isn't what you said. Thanks for trying anyway. This part was however only a minor oversight that caused the first exception and the main problem of locking was solved in a different way described in the comments to the question.